# Fastboot mode in my violet is blacked out

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot

The thing is when I get my phone into fastboot mode, the interface is like nothing; it's totally blacked out.

I thought of connecting it with my PC and it is detecting the phone successfully. But when I wrote the commands to detect the fastboot, it isn't showing up.

I'm very frustrated that I can't change my custom recovery. My custom recovery is showing some errors so I also can't change my ROM.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Blacked out means the logo isn't showing up

Comment: In fastboot mode no logo is shown. Only in stock recovery mode a "logo" (usually an Android robot in background) is shown. In fastboot/bootloader mode a text menu is shown, controllable via vol_up/vol_down + power.

Comment: By "violet", did you mean Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro (`violet`)?